# The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular8

I got this error when running ng serve command

> C:\Mysystem\Programs\myfwms>ng serve The serve command requires to be
>   run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be
>   found.

when i try this existing project getting this error

Comment: OK. But what is your question? Is myfwms an actual angular project that you created using ng new?

Comment: ng serve would work if you are in an actual angular project.If myfwms is not your angular project then go to your angular project directory and then try to run ng serve.

Comment: Please add more info, screenshots and logging. Please take a look to "how to ask": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add your angular.json file

Answer (score 0):

The above statement requires the angular project to be run in the same port where it is created. When the server has killed the system redirect the port to Localhost:4200 and localhost:8080. Therefore it faces difficulties in recoating the port:3000. Following command line can help to redirect the particular port from where it is created:
**npm run serve 1**